# Why does threading not work in a Flask app when its run with gunicorn?

Tags: flask, gunicorn

When files are uploaded to my flask app a thread id is generated. This is used by the frontend to later get the progress details of the file reading process (the cert_details route)

The cert_details route reads in data from a PDF using tesseract, opencv etc. This is quite a resource intensive process and can take a while to perform

While the process is running, I want to be able to update the front end with the progress (i.e how many files read in). Hence I have made a separate thread that has a value 'progress' that increases each time a file has been processed.

The app works without gunicorn i.e when the docker command is `CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]`

If I change it to use gunicorn `CMD ["gunicorn","--timeout", “60", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000", "app:app"]`  , the progress bar doesn't get updated until the file reading process has finished (which defeats the purpose of the progress bar).

Why does the threading not work with gunicorn? Is there an alternative approach that I have to take or could it be related to thread starvation?

```
import threading
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for, jsonify, send_from_directory, send_file
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)



class ExportingThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.progress = 0
        super().__init__()



exporting_threads = {}

@app.route('/uploads', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'files[]' not in request.files:
            
            return {'status':'File upload unsuccesful'}

        files = request.files.getlist('files[]')

        for file in files:
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            else:
                return {'status':'Non pdf file type uploaded'}   
        global thread_id
        thread_id = random.randint(0, 10000)
        return {'status':'sucessful'}

@app.route('/get_thread_id')
def get_thread():
    global thread_id
    return str(thread_id)

@app.route('/progress', methods=['POST'])
def progress():
    
    data = request.json
   
    thread_id = data['thread_id'] 
  
    global exporting_threads
    if thread_id in exporting_threads:
       return str(exporting_threads[thread_id].progress)
    else:
        return '0'   

@app.route('/cert_details', methods=['POST'])
def get_details():  
  
    data = request.json
   
    if 'filenames' not in data:
        return {'error':'filenames not found'}
    else:

        filenames =data['filenames']

        details =[]

        global exporting_threads
        global thread_id
        
        exporting_threads[thread_id] = ExportingThread()
        exporting_threads[thread_id].start()
        
        for file in filenames:
            #this is the resource intensive process using ocr / opencv
            details.append( get_certficate_details( UPLOAD_FOLDER_LOCATION + file, file ) )
            exporting_threads[thread_id].progress += 1
        
        return jsonify(file_details =  details)
```

Comment: did you find any solution?